# Able to connect to wifi fine in Debian w/GNOME, but in interface no networks are shown

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, gnome

I'm currently writing this on Debian, having connected to my wifi using commands from Terminal.

However, the NetworkManager interface (top-right corner > Wi-Fi > Select Network) shows 'No Networks'.

How can I make it show my network?

Answer (score 0):

In Debian, NetworkManager is configured to not manage network interfaces which are configured through `/etc/network/interfaces`. If you used `ifup` to configure it, then that is your problem.

You need to decide whether you want to use `ifup` or NetworkManager to configure your network interface. If the latter, just remove the configuration for your wireless interface from your `interfaces` file.