# No wifi networks show up in gnome settings

Tags: debian, wifi, gnome, network-interface

I've got a rather odd issue. I recently installed debian 8 on a Toshiba Kirabook and have some issues with the wifi. When going to the gnome wifi selection it says no networks available so I can't choose to connect to anything.

However I got the wifi to work by adding the following to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
...
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid <myssid>
    wpa-psk <mypassword>
```

I'm unhappy that I can't select different networks via the standard gnome interface. However I'm also unhappy to have my passwords stored in plain text like that.

How could I go about debugging this problem so that I'll be able to select different networks based on availability and most importantly via the gnome setting?

**Edit: solved**

[This question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236158/able-to-connect-to-wifi-fine-in-debian-w-gnome-but-in-interface-no-networks-are?rq=1) disscussed a similar issue and the solution was to remove the SSID from the interfaces. Apparently the network manager does not manages devices that are covered in /etc/network/interface.

After removing it, all networks showed up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your wifi driver properly installed? If not please follow:

```
Add a "non-free" component to /etc/apt/sources.list for your Debian version:

# Debian 8 "Jessie"
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

Update the list of available packages and install the firmware-ipw2x00 and wireless-tools packages:

# apt-get update
# apt-get install firmware-ipw2x00 wireless-tools
```

For more information refer to: https://wiki.debian.org/ipw2200